# Mudblazor Change DataGrid Form Layout

Tags: datagrid, blazor, mudblazor

i am working on an Blazor Project, using Mudblazor Datagrid to edit some Data. The Layout of the Form is not easy to read. Is it possible to style the Form? I would like to increase the width of the form and ad some spacer.
I didnt find anything in the mudblazor documentation

```
<PropertyColumn Property="x => x.Description" Title="Beschreibung" IsEditable="true" CellStyle="min-width: 1000px;" />
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: You could inspect the CSS in the webbrowser and change the css properties for that component.

Answer (score 0):

Could try the following, by using a template column instead of PropertyColumn. have not tested IsEditable ...

```
 <TemplateColumn Title="Beschreibung" IsEditable="true">
     <CellTemplate>
         <MudText Style="min-width:1000px;">@context.Item.Description</MudText>             
     </CellTemplate>
 </TemplateColumn>
```

ive used mudtext but could anything.